# Force.com Sites SSL Forwarding | HTTPS Only

Tags: force.com-sites, ssl

**Situation**

After creating, signing and deploying a new certificate for a custom domain we want to forward non-SSL connections to SSL and force our customers to use SSL.

**Question**

What is the best way to detect weather or not ssl is used to access a force.com site? What is the best way to forward customers from non ssl to ssl secured addresses?

Comment: Does the "Require Secure Connections (HTTPS)" checkbox on the Site configuration page not accomplish the redirection? Do you have a specific reason for logging how many users are hitting your site via HTTP?

Answer (score -1):

If you're OK with a client-side solution, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723213/detect-http-or-https-then-force-https-in-javascript) is pretty simple and has worked for me in the past. Some browser configurations may spawn a warning but I believe those are generally very old browsers.

Comment: your solution doesn't work at all. in general a 301 redirect is needed otherwise google will downrate your site.